# Unknown name in Terminal as username

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-mavericks

i bought a MacBook Pro with OSX version 10.9.2 (Mavericks)
since this, (about 2 month) i did not any attention to what happens in my Terminal when i start typing some code in it (java codes for compile or something) but now i got that when i just start my terminal, this totally unknown line will appeared:

**dukhat:~ MacBookpro$**

necessary to say, my basic mac user was macbookpro when i bought this mac
but what is this "dukhat"?!

i googled it but there is no related information about...

thanks for advances...

Answer (score 4):

Reset it using:

`sudo scutil --set HostName newhostname`

or

`sudo hostname -s newhostname`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else ending up here. Apple has a guide for this. Make sure to create a separate Administrator account before attempting.
http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201548

You have to log on with a second admin account and manually change the user folder **/Users/OldUserName** to **/Users/NewUserName**.
Then you go to **System Preferences** > **Users & Groups** where you unhinge the **Lock-icon** in the bottom-left. Thereafter you can **Ctrl-click** on the User that you want to change and select **Advanced Options...**
Then you can change the **Account name** to **NewUserName** and the **Home directory** to **/Users/NewUserName**.

This requires administrator privileges, and you might want to back up your data first.